# Ajax return error 500 no matter what file as url is given

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm getting a server 500 error with the code below. I've also tested it with a test file and still a 500 error. The file is set at 644.

This is the Ajax code.

```
function paynlSubmitPayment(userid ,credits ,profile ,bankId) {
paynlSubmitForm = false;
var newwin = paynlPaymentPopup('/Paynl/paynl-loading.html');
var product = jQuery("input[name='selectedProduct']").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Paynl/paynl-api.php",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        mode:'startPayment',
        product:product,
        profile:profile,
        idealBank:bankId,
        userid:userid,
        credits:credits
    }, 
    success: function(data) {
        if('TRUE' == data.result) {
            newwin.location.href = data.issuerUrl;
            newwin.focus();
        } else {
            newwin.close();
            alert(data.error);
        }
    },
    error: function(){
        newwin.close();
        alert('Fail');
    },
    complete: function() {
        paynlSubmitForm = true;
    }
});
} 
function paynlCheckFormSubmit() {
return paynlSubmitForm;
}
```

The loading popup works, but it shows me the error 'Fail' part.
I've also tried putting the whole url with http but still no success.
I can post the php file, but it seems like the error is somewhere in the Ajax because the test files didn't work either.

Edit

My PHP Code

```
<?php

# Include classes
include realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/Paynl/Paynl.php';
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/connect.php');

# Controleer of installer is doorlopen
if (!class_exists('PaynlConfigPPT') || !class_exists('PaynlConfigPPC')) {
trigger_error('Run installer first!', E_USER_ERROR);
die();
}


switch (strtoupper($_POST['mode'])) {
case 'STARTPAYMENT':
    try {
        # PPT transactie starten
        $paynlPPT = new PaynlPPT();
        $products = $paynlPPT->getProducts();

        # Bepaal bedrag aan de hand van de producten in de
        # config en het ID van het geselecteerde product
        $transactionValue = $products[$_POST['product']]['price'];

        # Bij ideal wordt een bank verwacht
        if (array_key_exists('idealBank', $_POST)) {
            if ((int) $_POST['idealBank'] <= 0) {
                # geen bank geselecteerd voor doorsturen naar internetbankieren.
                throw new PaynlException('Geen bank geselecteerd');
            }
            $idealBankId = (int) $_POST['idealBank'];
            $selectedProfile = PaynlPPT::PROFILE_ID_IDEAL;
        } else {
            # Geen ideal, dus bankId=null
            $idealBankId = null;
            $selectedProfile = (int) $_POST['profile'];
        }



        # Transactie submitten bij Pay.nl
        $paynlPPT->setProductId($_POST['product']);
        $data = $paynlPPT->startTransaction($transactionValue, $selectedProfile, $idealBankId);

        // CG - Insert Transaction Details

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO transactions(transid, amount, userid, pakket, credits, betaald, uts) VALUES('".$data['orderId']."','" . $transactionValue . "', '".$_POST['userid']."', '" . $_POST['product'] . "', '".$_POST['credits']."', 0, " . time() . ");") or die(mysql_error());

        // CG - Insert Transaction Details

    } catch (PaynlException $e) {
        $data = array(
            'result' => 'FALSE',
            'error' => $e->getMessage()
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
    break;
}
```

Comment: Your PHP code is causing the 500 error, not the JavaScript.

Comment: You claim `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` but then you encode your data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded. That's probably the problem, but since it is a server side error, you really need to look at the server side error report and the server side code.

Comment: Post your php code and you may get help.

Comment: Check the Development Tools for the Ajax call and see if PHP is showing any errors. If not, try to enable error reporting in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Code 500 means Internal Server Error. That means that something in your PHP script is crashing. The Ajax call itself is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read data from `$_POST` but PHP won't populate that if you send it JSON.

You said:

> ```
> contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
> ```

Which means "The content of this request is JSON". PHP will believe you and won't populate `$_POST`.

Since you aren't actually sending JSON, just remove that line.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I removed it but still the 500 error

Answer (score -1):

Do a `console.log(data)` of the data returned through AJAX and remove the :
 `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` in the AJAX options.

This way the PHP error message will be displayed in the Console.

Works for me.